# Angularjs : Not Getting initialized value

Tags: angularjs

I am getting the value inside {{total}} but when i am initializing this value in ng-init , not getting the value of total in ng-init

For example :

Calling this function when calculating total price:

ng-change HTML part:

```
   <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-lg-2  col-lg-offset-1  col-xs-12 ">
                <select class="form-control select-data pull-right mt10" ng-model="book.package[$index]" ng-change="get_total_price(x.price,book.package[$index],x.id)">
                    <option value="">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                    <option value="4">4</option>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    <option value="9">9</option>
                    <option value="10">10</option>
                    <option value="11">11</option>
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                </select>
       </div>

ng-change="get_total_price(x.price,book.package[$index],x.id);
```

From this i am getting the total price

```
${{total}}
```

Now i want to initialise this through ng-init like this

```
<input type="text" class="hidden" placeholder="Enter name" ng-init="book.total_price= total" ng-model="book.total_price">
```

but when i checked this through json like this

```
{{total_price | json}}
```

it's display the total_price 0 instead of which i'm getting in {{total}}

Can anyone help me to get this? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited :**

```
$scope.get_total_price = function ($price,$value,$id) { 
        $scope.total = $scope.total + Number($price)*Number($value);
};
```

This is the function by which i'm getting price value and returning to this my view and this return price i need to show initialized in ng-init.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: Please add ng-change html statement

Comment: Please check the html part of ng-change

Comment: it's not really clear what you are trying to calculate here;  you have 3 different variables that seem to be related, but it's unclear when and where you are trying to access each from.  on top of that, this *feels like* exactly what the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#!) for `ng-init` warns against; this is adding unnecessary logic.  You should always initialize your properties in your controller, not in your HTML.  if you *really feel like* using `ng-init` is a necessity, you should try to provide a [mcve] demonstrating why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This may be this help you

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.value = 0;
    $scope.book = {
      total_price : 0,
    }
    $scope.get_total_price = function (price,value,id) { 
         $scope.book.total_price =  $scope.book.total_price + Number(price) * Number(value);
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <span>Total:- {{book.total_price}}</span>
  <br>
   <select ng-model="value" ng-change="get_total_price(2,1,1)">
       <option value="">0</option>
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
       <option value="3">3</option>
       <option value="4">4</option>
       <option value="5">5</option>
       <option value="6">6</option>
       <option value="7">7</option>
       <option value="8">8</option>
       <option value="9">9</option>
       <option value="10">10</option>
       <option value="11">11</option>
       <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <br>
 <input type="text" class="hidden" placeholder="Enter name" ng-model="book.total_price">
<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have initialized `book.total_price` object not `total_price`.

Your `total_price` object is inside of the `book` object. So you should write the code like `{{book.total_price | json}}` instead of `{{total_price | json}}`.

Comment: Actually here book is array which also contain values other than total_price. But still i wrote this and  not getting changed price value,it's still displaying 0 rather than actual price

Comment: Could you please provide jsfiddle? unless I couldn't find the issue.  But let me know if you check with `{{yourarray[0].total_price | json}}`.

Comment: Please check my edited part. i have added the function from where i'm getting the total price.

Comment: @user6891871 did you initialize ` $scope.total = 0 ` in globally?

Comment: @user6891871 Can you please change the parameters name `$price,$value,$id` to `price,value,id`?

Comment: **There are certain parts of Angular that do ignore prefixed properties, for example the 'json' filter will not output a variable starting with '$'**

Comment: I have remove $ sign and it's returning the sane calculated price but getting through in ng-init